# How to change app theme from ordinary "Blank Activity" to "Master/Detail Flow"

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I have an application that works on the basic theme "Blank Activity" and what i would like to do is to change it to a "Master/Detail Flow" theme. I do know that this will make my application work on android SDK 11 + (android 3.0 Honeycomb +), that is OK with me. The issue is i don't know where to start from, what are the basic steps to make this BIG conversion? I couldn't find any example to help me out with this issue. What should i be looking for. i am sure this has been done, can you at least please give me some pointer on how to do this?
my Application is not that complicated it uses activities, async tasks, DB, custom lists,... it is very basic. I use the custom list to display data and when i click on it it displays much more details, so I thought what better way to do this in a more professorial matter than the "Master/Detail Flow". If you have any tutorial regarding the "Master/Detail Flow" that you can hook me up with that might help.

Comment: Note: I personally hate that layout, the side panel takes too much of the screen for no purpose. I would consider the DrawerLayout, link: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: @LuckyMe thanks, but that is not what i was asking for.

Comment: I know, that is why I didn't put it as an answer...

Comment: @LuckyMe The two are not interchangable at all. The `DrawerLayout` is meant to be used with a fixed set of application-level navigation items. The Master/Detail flow is meant to display a list of items and details about each of those items (i.e. emails and their text contents, text messages and their message content, etc.).

Comment: @AlexLockwood I don't understand the difference you are speaking of? Both have a list and a view to display content based on the item selected. And I don't see how the `DrawerLayout` is meant to have fixed content in contrast with the `MasterLayout`. What you are saying seems to be an opinion wrapped in a speculation, nothing of any official design intent. If you could clarify more?

Comment: Would you use the `DrawerLayout` for something like the Gmail app on tablets?

Comment: @AlexLockwood The Gmail app already uses that on tablets and phones. And yes, I would use it actually. I find the `MasterLayout` to render too much of the screen useless. The panel (list) is not used very frequently, and I would like the content to occupy as much of the screen as possible. The `MasterLayout` goes very against that methodology.

Comment: @LuckyMe Let me be more clear. You would replace the master/detail flow with the drawer layout? So you would use a drawer layout to display a list of emails on the left side of the screen like in this screenshot: http://goo.gl/gQtOI5. The two patterns aren't interchangeable... that's all I'm saying.

Comment: Oh, you are right, It was an oversight on my end. I was thinking of the portrait two panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have an application that works on the basic theme "Blank Activity"
>   and what i would like to do is to change it to a Master/Detail Flow"
>   theme.

I think a change of the application flow would be more appropriate then a change of theme. Two obvious questions that would appear are why do you suddenly want to make this change and are sure your app makes sense in a master/detail flow? The answer would most likely be positive but you should answer them nonetheless.

> I do know that this will make my application work on android SDK 11 +
>   (android 3.0 Honeycomb +), that is OK with me

I don't see why you're app couldn't run on versions below with the new master/detail stuff.

> The issue is i don't know where to start from, what are the basic
>   steps to make this BIG conversion? I couldn't find any example to help
>   me out with this issue. What should i be looking for. i am sure this
>   has been done, can you at least please give me some pointer on how to
>   do this?

You haven't provided details about how is your app implemented. The change would revolve around fragments so a BIG question would be if the current single pane version is built using the fragments framework.

If your app is built using fragments then making the change shouldn't be too hard. You'd need to:

- establish which parts(fragments) should be combined in an activity(from your old ones) to make the master/detail(when the space would allow it)
- change the multi pane activity to accommodate the new fragment(s). This should be easy to do but it would depend on the size of the features exposed by each of those fragments.
- modify the rest of the activities(for when the app will not run in the multi pane mode), this would be small changes as the activities would mainly remain as the current version

If your app isn't built using fragments, then what I said above still applies but you'd need to also actually make the required fragments wrapping whatever functionality your app has. This would most likely result in a big code refactoring.

Comment: I updated my question, have a look. I do understand this might be a big job, but I am willing to do it

Comment: @user2443241 I've seen the edit. I'm not sure however what kind of tutorial do you expect to find. From the edit I'm assuming that you don't have fragments now, in this case you may want to simply create a new project using the master/detail template and start refactoring code from the old project in the pieces provided by that template project(the fragments). This way you could easily see the connections required.

Comment: I already have my application in the play store, i would like it as an update to my old one, is that possible with a new project?

Comment: @user2443241 Yes, as long as the new project has the exact same package name, you increment the version(of the old project) in the new manifest and you sign the new app with the same certificate you used for the initial project.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try that. The tutorial that I am looking for is a one for "Master/Detail Flow" with a good example

Comment: @user2443241 I don't know about such tutorial. However if you create a simple master/detail project you could just look at its initial components and see how stuff works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial about the Master/Detail template in Android - [An Android Master/Detail Flow Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial).

As far as I understand your application is up and running - so I'm not sure whether it is worth it to try rewriting it, unless you are experiencing some problems of course. :)
In general the master/details flow requires the following steps:

- Implement a `ListFragment` showing basic information of your items
- Implement a `Fragment` showing detailed information about a particular item
- Make an xml layout file for large devices (located in `layout-sw600dp` folder for example). In this layout you have to put both your fragments.
- Write a general version of this layout file (i.e. file with the same name but located in the `layout` folder), which contains only the ListFragment.
- Let your activity handle `onItemClick` event from the `ListFragment`. Each time an item is clicked, you have to check if the activity is showing both fragments or only the `ListFragment`. If both are visible, you have to notify the details fragment that new item is selected so it can show its data. Otherwise you have to create new details fragment (you reuse it of course), pass it some information about the selected item (so it can show the item's data) and replace the `ListFragment` with the new one.

That a basic overview, but it should be enough to give you some idea about this flow. If you need any more details - just let me know. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links from developer.android.com [fragment-ui](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) and [adaptui](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html)

These are some guidelines about fragments but they are told using a master/Detail app.

Also dont forget to checkout the news reader app provided as sample in the second link.

Answer (score 2):

Master/detail flow and blank activity is not same as you want to change by only changing app theme or app base theme. It will be better, if you first design master/detail flow template using UI fragments, then according integrate you blank activity with the master template making necessary changes. And for master/detail flow tutorial just google it, you will find lots of example there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent version of the Android SDK, you should be able to create a new Android application and during that process you can elect to have the wizard create a Master/Detail Flow app for you. It will create a basic working app so that you can look through the code and understand the necessary parts.

Then, depending on how simple your app is, you may want to move all your present code to the new application or vise versa.

Macro changes that will happen:

1. Change all your current Activities to `extend Fragment` instead.
2. You will have to create a FragmentActivity to call your Fragments. This will basically be the boilerplate code, with just the names of your Fragments added to it.
3. Don't forget to double check your Manifest!

In your converted Fragments that previously extended Activity:

1. Everywhere you needed a Context, switch that with `getActivty()` (or create a global variable so that it is only called once)
2. Change `onCreate()` to

   ```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signals, container, false);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Add if you want to display a Menu
        // Your initiation code here
       return mView;
   }
   ```
3. If you have a menu, change it to

   ```
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
   }
   ```

And that's it for basic applications. When you first change Activities to Fragments, there will be many errors. But, they are all easy to fix.